# are brin indexes okay to use on two column?

Tags: postgresql

I have for a table with two columns:

- frame
- seqnum

`frame` is increasing sequentially whilst `seqnum` is sequentially increasing but resets when frame increases:

```sql
frame 0 , seqnum 1, 
frame 0 , seqnum 2, 
frame 1 , seqnum 1, 
frame 2 , seqnum 1, 
frame 2 , seqnum 2,
```

would it be good to use brin indexes to index the two columns or would something else be better?

Comment: "good" or "better" in order to achieve *what*?

Comment: I know that brin works well as an index for things like a single column log of timestamps. I'm just trying to understand if it can be used here.

Comment: Again: In order to achieve ***what***, i.e. to support which queries?

Comment: @zcaudate in order to identify the best index type you need to take a few things into consideration, namely the `where` clause of your queries (which operators, = ~~ ~~* < > ? ), how often the table is updated, amount of records and the data itself (does it have many repeating items?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rows are inserted in the order you quote, then this is a rare case wher a multi-column BRIN index can be useful.

It will speed up queries with `WHERE` conditions like

```
WHERE frame = 42 AND seqnum = 12
```

or

```
WHERE (frame, seqnum) < (42, 12)
```

Note that BRIN indexes only work well on tables that never receive `DELETE`s or `UPDATE`s, and where the rows are all of about the same size (because otherwise a later, small row might fit into a gap left in an "older" block.

Comment: Your note only applies for sequence columns.

Answer (score 1):

Since seqnum cycles rather than increasing monotonically (or having some other regional clustering), it will do no good to include it in a BRIN index.  It probably won't do any great harm, either, though.  The columns of BRIN indexes are all pretty much independent of each other, unlike a btree index.  Each one has to separately be monotonic or otherwise clustered to be much good.

Whether you need a different index depend on what queries you want to support, and what your data looks like.  If seqnum only has the values of 1,2, maybe 3 through hundreds of millions of cycles, there probably isn't much point in indexing it at all.